# Extend existing wifi using unix pc access point (with same SSID)

Tags: ubuntu, nmcli, wifi-hotspot, access-point, connection-sharing

### Context

I have a PC running Ubuntu Server and connected to my internet provider’s router using an ethernet connection (and that has a static IP set up in the router's portal).

The internet provider’s router provides a native wifi network that is too weak in several rooms to be usable there.

The PC is placed in a room where the signal is weak and I was able to create an access point using `nmcli` (details below).

### Goal

What I would like to achieve is to have the access point wifi to share the router’s wifi SSID and password so that the main wifi is extended rather than separate. That way, devices would just switch access points using in appearance the same wifi network.

### Access Point Configuration

My current nm configuration is as follows :

```
[connection]
id=<connection name>
uuid=<...>
type=wifi
interface-name=<interface name>
permissions=
timestamp=<...>

[wifi]
band=bg
channel=1
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=ap
seen-bssids=<...>
ssid=<internet provider wifi ssid>_private

[wifi-security]
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=<internet provider wifi password>

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

### Hints I have so far

My understanding is that in principle I should change the SSID to be my internet provider's wifi SSID and disable the access point DHCP.

However, I don't understand how to do that after a while searching the internet.

I tried setting the `ipv4` and `ipv6` `method`s to `disabled` but when I connected to the wifi with my phone I got disconnected almost instantly afterwards until I restored it.

The internet provider's wifi is using `WPA2 - AES` as security setting and the channel `6` (that's why I chose `wpa-psk`, `rsn` and channel `1` in my nm configuration).

Any advice is appreciated.